# export from a while loop to a csv file

Tags: bash, csv

Given the following script and dataset:
Script:

```
while IFS="," 
   read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13; 
   do if [ -z "$v12" ]; 
      then echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,'unknown',$v13"; 
   else echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13"; 
   fi;
done 
>train3.csv
```

Dataset:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C
```

I want to export as a CSV file with name 'train3.csv' but the way I'm doing don't work and it doesn't show the changes done or saves as a CSV file.

How can I solve this?

The expected result would be:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,'unknown',S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,'unknown',S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,'unknown',S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,'unknown',Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,'unknown',S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,'unknown',S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,'unknown',C
```

also including a new CSV file creation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Bash for this. Your input CSV contains quoted strings. You probably have no guarantee, that a quoted string must contain exactly one comma. If it contains less or more commas, this will break your code.

Instead use a dedicated tool, which handles quoted strings correctly. The easiest tool to use is Perl with the module [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV). The following command will install it on Debian.

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-csv-perl
```

Now you can use SQL to fix your CSV files.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:")
    or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("UPDATE train3.csv SET cabin = ? WHERE cabin is null");
$sth->execute ("'unknown'");
$sth->finish;

$dbh->disconnect;
```

If you do not want to learn Perl, you can use the script as a ready to use program from your command line. Save it in `csv.pl` and make it executable:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:")
    or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare (shift);
$sth->execute (@ARGV);
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Next you can pass just the query and its arguments:

```
./csv.pl 'UPDATE train3.csv SET cabin = ? WHERE cabin is null' \'unknown\'
```

Keep an eye on the quoting.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is not working, because the `read` doesn't know where to read from and the redirection should be right after `done`.
I also improved the script with parameter assignment: `${parameter:-word}` will use `word` when the parameter is empty.

```
while IFS="," read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13; do
  echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,${v12:-'unknown'},$v13"
done <dataset.csv >train3.csv
```

You can avoid the `while` loop with another tool

```
awk -F, -v unknown="'unknown'" 'BEGIN { OFS="," } !$12 {$12=unknown} 1' < dataset.csv >train3.csv
```

Both solutions will get confused by the comma in field 2 (that is why field 12, not 11, is changed). With a name without comma the wrong field is examined.
When you know that `Embarked` is a field without comma, you can use

```
awk -F, -v unknown="'unknown'" '
  BEGIN { OFS="," } 
  !$(NF-1) {$(NF-1)=unknown}
  1' < dataset.csv >train3.csv
```

However, you should use a solution that really understands the csv format, like the answer of @ceving.

Comment: It looks good but I need to execute the script as ``` ./script.sh <file.csv``` and this means I can't have inside the script the file mentioned. Would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, just remove `< dataset.csv`. You might edit your question and explain how you call the script.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash

datafile='dataset.txt'
outputfile='train3.csv'
>"$outputfile"

while IFS="," read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13
do
    if [[ -z "$v12" ]]
    then
        echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,'unknown',$v13"
    else
        echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13"
    fi
done < "$datafile" >"$outputfile"
```

A great reference for reading data from files is https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: It is better to move `>>"$outputfile"` outside the loop (less opening/closing the file), just after `done`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, modified.